# Verify Knuth shuffle algorithm is as unbiased as possible

Tags: c++, algorithm, shuffle, random, knuth

I'm implementing a [Knuth shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) for a C++ project I'm working on. I'm trying to get the most unbiased results from my shuffle (and I'm not an expert on (pseudo)random number generation). I just want to make sure this is the most unbiased shuffle implementation.

`draw_t` is a byte type (`typedef`'d to `unsigned char`). `items` is the count of items in the list. I've included the code for `random::get( draw_t max )` below.

```
for( draw_t pull_index = (items - 1); pull_index > 1; pull_index-- )
{
    draw_t push_index = random::get( pull_index );

    draw_t push_item = this->_list[push_index];
    draw_t pull_item = this->_list[pull_index];

    this->_list[push_index] = pull_item;
    this->_list[pull_index] = push_item;
}
```

The random function I'm using has been modified to eliminate [modulo bias](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuffling#Modulo_bias). `RAND_MAX` is assigned to `random::_internal_max`.

```
draw_t random::get( draw_t max )
{
    if( random::_is_seeded == false )
    {
        random::seed( );
    }

    int rand_value = random::_internal_max;
    int max_rand_value = random::_internal_max - ( max - ( random::_internal_max % max ) );

    do
    {
        rand_value = ::rand( );
    } while( rand_value >= max_rand_value );

    return static_cast< draw_t >( rand_value % max );
}
```

Comment: Side note: The c++ STL includes the algorithm `random_shuffle`. Just in case you didn't know.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the STL's implementation. I haven't taken the time to learn the STL yet (I'm just a Win32/.NET guy) and I'd like there to be a minimal learning curve on this project (time constraints) but I'll take that into consideration.

Comment: How many different states can your random number generator have? If it's less than 52! then there will be shuffles that can never be produced (note that 2^32 or even 2^64 is much smaller than 52!). You need to use a RNG with a lot more states than 52! if you want to get unbiased results: perhaps try the Mersenne Twister.

Comment: The C++ STL also (now) includes RNGs that are awesome, for this exact purpose

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, one thing you could do as a black-box test is take some relatively small array size, perform a large number of shuffles on it, count how many times you observe each permutation, and then perform [Pearson's Chi-square](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-square_test) test to determine whether the results are uniformly distributed over the permutation space.

On the other hand, the Knuth shuffle, AKA the Fisher-Yates shuffle, is proven to be unbiased as long as the random number generator that the indices are coming from is unbiased.

Comment: I'll look into permutation counting; Pearson's Chi-square test (as far as I've read up on it) looks a little out of my league as far as mathematics are concerned, but I'll continue reading up on it.

Comment: You don't really need to go as far as Chi-square to test whether the shuffle is biased. Something as simple as standard deviation will work with the same type of test (you should see the standard deviation approach zero as the number of shuffles increases).

Comment: @Adam:  I just thought it would be easy to use Chi-square because I wrote a library function that did Pearson's Chi-square a while back.  I've since forgotten the details of how it works, but I still remember how to use it.  The only problem is it's written in D, not C++.  There should be C++ libs that do this, but if you don't have one conveniently available (installed, etc) already, then it may be overkill.

Comment: @dsimcha: would you be willing to share your D library for Chi-square? I'm sure I could port it to C++ (for personal use only, of course) without much trouble. (You can reach me at firstname dot lastname at gmail.)

Comment: But it's actually a whole statistics lib.  The actual chi-square function is pretty short, but you'd have to port or find C++ equivalents of a whole bunch of lower-level functionality, like incomplete gamma functions.  It's probably overkill, but I figured I'd share it with you just in case it isn't.  Alternatively, you can just have your C++ code print out the values and paste them into a statistics package like R, or even just eyeball them instead of doing a formal test, if this testing doesn't have to be fully automated.

Answer (score 8):

If I see that right, your `random::get (max)` doesn't include `max`.

This line:

```
draw_t push_index = random::get( pull_index );
```

then produces a "classical" off-by-one error, as your `pull_index` and `push_index` erroneously can never be the same.  This produces a subtle bias that you can never have an item where it was before the shuffle.  In an extreme example, two-item lists under this "shuffle" would always be reversed.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at this article from Jeff Atwood:

**Shuffling**
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001008.html

See also:

**The Danger of Naïveté**
http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001015.html

Comment: I'm aware of the general limitations of pseudorandom number generators; do you think I should look into moving to Eric Lippert's algorithm (assign each index a random floating point value and sort) or beefing up my random number generator, perhaps by tapping a cryptography API or implementing a better PRNG like the Mersenne Twister or Blum Blum Shub?

Comment: Actually, I missed the best post.  See: The Danger of Naïveté -- http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001015.html

Answer (score 2):

The Knuth shuffle itself is provably unbiased: There exists exactly one series of operations that yields each possible shuffle. It's unlikely your PRNG has enough bits of state to express every possible shuffle, however, so the real question is if your PRNG is 'random enough' with regards to the set of shuffles it will actually produce, and whether your seeding strategy is secure enough.

Only you can decide this, as it depends on the consequences of a shuffle that isn't random enough. If you're dealing with real money, for example, I would suggest switching to a cryptographically secure PRNG and improving your seeding strategy. Although most built in PRNGs generate good randomness, they're also quite easy to reverse engineer, and calling seed() with no arguments is likely seeding based on the current time, which is pretty easy to predict.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cstdlib> // srand() && rand()

/** Shufle the first 'dim' values in array 'V[]'.
    - Implements the Fisher–Yates_shuffle.
    - Uses the standard function 'rand()' for randomness.
    - Initialices the random sequence using 'seed'.
    - Uses 'dim' swaps.
    \see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685339/
    \see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#The_modern_algorithm
*/
template <class T>
void Fisher_Yates_shuffle( T* V, unsigned dim , unsigned seed ) {
    srand(seed);
    T temp;
    unsigned i,iPP;

    i   = dim-1;
    iPP = dim;
    while ( i>0 ) {
        unsigned j = rand() % iPP;
        if ( i!=j ) { // swap
            temp = V[i]; V[i] = V[j]; V[j] = temp;
        }
        iPP = i;
        --i;
    }
/*
    This implementation depends on the randomness of the random number
    generator used ['rand()' in this case].
*/
}
```